# Python library for topic tagging / scoring of sentences with specific topic set

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling

I am looking for the best python library for achieving below NLP task.

Given an example sentence, "he becomes king maha vajiralongkorn bodindradebayavarangkun the 10th monarch of the chakri dynasty but will also be known as rama x i would like to accept in order to fulfill his majestys wishes and for the benefit of all thais " (A sentence taken from this article http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-38168912)

I would like to compute topic scores for this sentences. For example, if I define my "topic set" to be {"politics", "tech", "business", "health", "entertainment"},

I would like output such as: {"politics" : 0.9, "tech" : 0.1, "business": 0.1, "health" : 0.05, "entertainment" : 0.2}

The key thing I am trying to achieve is that I would like to define my topic set and to have scores for topic in that set only. Also, sentences would be relatively short and I would like to compute outputs for sentences that come in streaming fashion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Topic Modelling is still a difficult problem so don't expect perfect results out of the box (esp. without a good training corpus from your target domain).

That being said, I had good luck with the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html) package, in particular I would take a look at their [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation) module.